# Is there a way to modify a jQuery object itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using function like `.add`, `.remove`, etc. on a jquery object, the jQuery object itself isn't modified, the result get caught by the returned new jQuery object.

Is there a way to modify the object itself?

I'd need that so I can write a function with a jQuery passed by reference, something like this :

```
function DoThings(refJQuery) {
    refJQuery.find(...).remove(...);

    if (refJQuery.length > 0) {
        DoThings(refJQuery);
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: this sample of code is just a reminder for purpose/usage of "value passed by reference".

Comment: @Satpal No : This doesn't change the jQuery object.

Comment: that's not working on the object itself, that's assigning the new result which breaks the "passed by reference" requirement.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to hack the properties of the jQuery object, wrapping it would be the correct way.

Comment: A jQuery extension method here would be a hack. A proper solution would be to wrap the jQuery object in a custom one.

Comment: methods like `remove` update the DOM, if you want an updated view of the DOM, you'll have to get it again. This seems like an x/y problem, even when using `find` to find descendant elements, and then removing those, the parent element will still be there, and it will never have a length of `0`

Comment: To see if the children was removed, you **have** to do `if (refJQuery.find(...).length > 0) { ...`

Comment: Please describe the intended use of this code (an example of the calling code that makes the intention clear). That will potentially result in simpler answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, jQuery collections are designed as immutable (you *could* change their properties but you're not supposed to, they're part of the implementation, not the API)

Composition is usually the way to go when you want to pass a immutable object to a function and have it modified (assuming taking a return value isn't feasible).

Normally, you should use a custom object. But you can also devise a generic decorator if you want:

```
function MutableJQueryObject(jqo){
  this.jqo = jqo;
}
['add','find','filter',].forEach(function(k){
    MutableJQueryObject.prototype[k] = function(){
      this.jqo = $.fn[k].apply(this.jqo, arguments);
    }
});
['html','remove'].forEach(function(k){
    MutableJQueryObject.prototype[k] = function(){
      return this.jqo[k].apply(this.jqo, arguments);
    }
});
$.fn.mutable = function(){
  return new MutableJQueryObject(this);
}
```

So you would build a mutable object :

```
var $e = $('body').mutable();
console.log($e.html()); // html of the body
(function($c){
    $c.find('div'); // change the object
})($e);
console.log($e.html()); // html of the div
```